# cast a hex into binary in Redshift

Tags: binary, hex, amazon-redshift

Is there a way in Redshift to convert a hex string into its binary representation?
For example in R i can use `BMS::hex2bin`

```
library(BMS)
hex2bin("090A")
hex2bin("3BFF")
 [1] 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
 [1] 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

and then I can work out the overlap between 2 hex strings with:

```
hex2bin("090A") * hex2bin("3BFF")
 [1] 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
```

is there an equivalent in Redshift?

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent Redshift function is FROM_HEX() - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_FROM_HEX.html

Comment: thank you, unfortunately `select from_hex('090A')' does not produce the binary output.  I've now found the answer so i'll post it.

Answer (score 0):

I found what i needed, it's a combination of `from_varbyte` and `from_hex`:

```
select '090A' as area1_hex
     , '3BFF' as area2_hex
   ,FROM_VARBYTE(from_hex('090A'), 'binary') as area1_bin
   ,FROM_VARBYTE(from_hex('3BFF'), 'binary') as area2_bin
   , strtol('090A', 16) & strtol('3BFF', 16) as overlap_int
   , to_hex(overlap_int::smallint::varbyte)  as overlap_hex
   ,FROM_VARBYTE(from_hex(overlap_hex), 'binary') as overlap_bin
;
```

gives:

| area1_hex | area2_hex | area1_bin | area2_bin | overlap_int | overlap_hex | overlap_bin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 090A | 3BFF | 0000100100001010 | 0011101111111111 | 2314 | 090a | 0000100100001010 |